# What exactly is the reason as to why the solution space of the characteristic equation of a matrix give the eigenvalues of that matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

After studying some linear algebra, i've learned about how the $\lambda$'s satisfying det$(A-\lambda I)=0$ are eigenvalues of $A$. But I am failing to see the connection as to why. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenvectors solve $Ax=\lambda x$, but $\lambda x=\lambda Ix$.  Therefore, $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.  In other words, $x$ is an eigenvector of $A-\lambda I$ with eigenvalue zero.  Having a zero eigenvector occurs only when the determinant is zero, which corresponds to roots of the characteristic equation.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then there is a nonzero vector $v$ such that $(M-\lambda I)v=0$. Thus this matrix is not invertible and has determinant $0$.